# Lost Physical connection

Tags: vb.net

I am seeing this error in a log file very day:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

The code in question performs 5000 deletions per day.  There are three or four database connections per deletion.

Initially I thought there was a problem with the code (ADO.NET) i.e. connections in the connection pool being used up because of undisposed resources e.g. Connections, Commands and datareaders.  I have come across the following code, which was written by someone else:

```
Public Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal connectionString As String, _
                                                       ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                                       ByVal commandText As String, _
                                                       ByVal ParamArray commandParameters() As DbParameter) As DbDataReader
            If (connectionString Is Nothing OrElse connectionString.Length = 0) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("connectionString")

            ' Create & open a SqlConnection
            Dim connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
            Try
                connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                connection.Open()
                ' Call the private overload that takes an internally owned connection in place of the connection string
                Return ExecuteReader(connection, CType(Nothing, SqlTransaction), commandType, commandText, commandParameters, dbConnectionOwnership.Internal)
            Catch
                ' If we fail to return the SqlDatReader, we need to close the connection ourselves
                If Not connection Is Nothing Then connection.Dispose()
                Throw
            End Try
        End Function

Private Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal connection As DbConnection, _
                                                            ByVal transaction As DbTransaction, _
                                                            ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                                            ByVal commandText As String, _
                                                            ByVal commandParameters() As DbParameter, _
                                                            ByVal connectionOwnership As dbConnectionOwnership, Optional ByVal intTimeOut As Integer = 30) As DbDataReader

            If (connection Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("connection")

            Dim mustCloseConnection As Boolean = False
            Dim cmd As DbCommand
            ' Create a command and prepare it for execution
            If TypeOf (connection) Is SqlConnection Then
                cmd = New SqlCommand
            ElseIf TypeOf (connection) Is OracleConnection Then
                cmd = New OracleCommand
            Else
                cmd = Nothing
            End If
            cmd.CommandTimeout = intTimeOut
            Try
                ' Create a reader
                Dim dataReader As DbDataReader

                PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, mustCloseConnection)
                ' Call ExecuteReader with the appropriate CommandBehavior
                If connectionOwnership = dbConnectionOwnership.External Then
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Else
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                End If

                ' Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
                Dim canClear As Boolean = True
                Dim commandParameter As DbParameter
                For Each commandParameter In cmd.Parameters
                    If commandParameter.Direction <> ParameterDirection.Input Then
                        canClear = False
                    End If
                Next

                If (canClear) Then cmd.Parameters.Clear()

                Return dataReader
            Catch
                If (mustCloseConnection) Then connection.Close()
                Throw
            End Try
        End Function

Private Shared Sub PrepareCommand(ByVal command As DbCommand, _
                                          ByVal connection As DbConnection, _
                                          ByVal transaction As DbTransaction, _
                                          ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                          ByVal commandText As String, _
                                          ByVal commandParameters() As DbParameter, ByRef mustCloseConnection As Boolean)

        If (command Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("command")
        If (commandText Is Nothing OrElse commandText.Length = 0) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("commandText")

        ' If the provided connection is not open, we will open it
        If connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            connection.Open()
            mustCloseConnection = True
        Else
            mustCloseConnection = False
        End If

        ' Associate the connection with the command
        command.Connection = connection

        ' Set the command text (stored procedure name or SQL statement)
        command.CommandText = commandText

        ' If we were provided a transaction, assign it.
        If Not (transaction Is Nothing) Then
            If transaction.Connection Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("The transaction was rollbacked or commited, please provide an open transaction.", "transaction")
            command.Transaction = transaction
        End If

        ' Set the command type
        command.CommandType = commandType

        ' Attach the command parameters if they are provided
        If Not (commandParameters Is Nothing) Then
            AttachParameters(command, commandParameters)
        End If
        Return
    End Sub ' PrepareCommand
```

I believe this was part of Code Blocks, which was downloaded from the Microsoft website in 2008.  I believe that this code is not destroying the connection object (unless an exception is thrown).  I guess this could be the cause?

Comment: You should check to the inner ExecuteReader to which the connection is passed.

Comment: @Steve, I have edited the code.  I was meant to include the inner function.

Comment: The datareader has been opened with CommandBehavior.CloseConnection. Thus you need to call Close on it to close the connection. But because the reader is passed back to the original caller (and I suppose that it is required to be open) you can't do anything here to properly close the connection. In my opinion is a very weak code prone to leaking resources. However I can't tell if this is the cause of your original source problem.

Comment: @Steve, I have added the 'Prepare' function.  I cannot see how the command object is disposed?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your connection in a USING block so it gets closed and disposed of property, regardless of an error or not. For example:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            ' Call the private overload that takes an internally owned connection in place of the connection string
            Return ExecuteReader(connection, CType(Nothing, SqlTransaction), commandType, commandText, commandParameters, dbConnectionOwnership.Internal)
        Catch
            ' If we fail to return the SqlDatReader, we need to close the connection ourselves
            Throw
        End Try
End Using
```

I usually see this error if the connection is left open and then some glitch in the network happens, then you try to use the connection. Not to say that is your issue, but the USING statement will definitely be an improvement to your code.