# Disposing of a Command/Data Reader object

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below from the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Public Sub ReadOrderData(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Dim queryString As String = _
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;" 
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Try 
            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", _
                    reader(0), reader(1)))
            End While 
        Finally 
            ' Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close()
        End Try 
    End Using 
End Sub
```

The SQLCommand object is not wrapped in a Using statement.  However, the code in this question (for example) is: [SqlCommand with using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185990/sqlcommand-with-using-statement)

I see lots of code that contains Data Readers and Commands that are not wrapped in Using statements.  Commands and Data Readers implement IDisposable.  Do you have to wrap them in Using statements/call .dispose?

One idea I have is that DataReaders and Commands are closed implicitly when the connection they link to is disposed.  Is that correct?

Comment: MSDN examples are often missing Dispose/Using steps in graphics and DB objects.  There is no link between a Command and dbReader though: the dbReader is a function return and it does not save a reference to it.

Comment: You must explicitly call the Close method when you are through using the SqlDataReader to use the associated SqlConnection for any other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The data reader and command are not closed or disposed when the connection is disposed. They are left unusable, as they have a reference to a connection that is no longer active.

Leaving them without disposing doesn't put any pressure on the database, but it causes more work for the garbage collector.

When the objects are disposed, they are removed from the finalizer queue, so that the garbage collector can remove them in one pass.

If left without disposing, the garbage collector first have to move them to the freachable queue, where a background thread will call the `Finalize` method on them, one by one. After that the garbage collector can remove them.

Comment: Thanks +1.  Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722030/lost-physical-connection.  I see this error in a log file.  Do you think that undisposed command objects could cause this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You should always use `Using` statements.

You will see lots of broken code around the internet.

Comment: While I agree that you definitely should, does that really answer the question?

Comment: @slaks, thanks. Does disposing of a connection dispose of a command as well?